# presentModalViewController not animating

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm calling presentModalViewController on a controller, and while the controller does come up, it's not animated when it comes on screen. Any ideas why that might be happening. I dont think it has anything to do with viewcontroller i'm calling it from (self), because I tried it with a basic viewcontroller and it worked....rather, i think it has something to do with the viewcontroller i'm trying to present. only interesting thing about my viewcontroller is it uses AVfoundation...but I've commented all of that code out and still get that.

Any ideas why that might be happening

```
MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc] init];
myController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
[myController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the above code.

I've created a small test project so you can see your code being executed to present the modal controller with animation.

Download at https://github.com/MaxMacleod/ControllerTest